# How to display StopWatch() time constantly?

Tags: android, flutter

So i'm stuck getting my time on stopwatch() to display time count constantly on my flutter app

How should i use stopWatch() to display time on flutter app ?

Comment: Can you put the code please?

Answer (score 2):

Check the link below, It guide you on how to build a complete stop watch application in Flutter:

[Flutter Stop watch](https://iosexample.com/sample-stopwatch-app-built-in-flutter/)

There is also a flutter `Package` to do this: the link to the package is below:

[Stopwatch package](https://pub.dev/packages/stop_watch_timer)

I hope this answers your question

Comment: this look promising .Thank you !